# How to automatically draw several plots for several dataframe together in R?

Tags: r, plot

I have several dataframes they are the same type only different values, how to generate same type of plots one by one?

I usually do:

```
A = df1
B = df2
C = df3

plot(A)
plot(B)
plot(C)
```

Can I do it in a simple way just use A, B, C names?

Comment: with a list: `l.df <- list(A=df1,B=df2,C=df3); invisible(lapply(l.df,plot))`

Comment: Thanks! it works!